# Query HTML tags from the command line (like jq does for JSON)

Tags: html, parser, shell-scripting

With [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) one can query data in JSON files from the command line, what is useful for example when writing bash scripts, which just need one entry from a JSON file, like this

```
jq '.[0] | {message: .commit.message, name: .commit.committer.name}'
```

(Example taken from the [tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/))

I wonder if there are similar tools for HTML, which may for example accept an XPath or CSS selector as query and return the matching element(s).

Comment: https://github.com/ericchiang/pup

Comment: https://github.com/mgdm/htmlq

Comment: @glennjackman maybe this was just too easy. It is not packaged by my distribution (yet), but probably not too hard to compile. Do you like to make it an answer?

Comment: No need. You could write your own answer letting us know what solution you chose, and your reasons for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

I found this one https://github.com/mgdm/htmlq. There are some examples on the github page. e,i you can do something like this:

```
curl --silent https://www.rust-lang.org/ | htmlq '#get-help'
```